# How to persist the charts I made through pygwalker?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-3.7

I am using Pygwalker to create some charts for my analysis, but I am unable to save the charts I have created.

Every time I reopen the notebook or refresh the notebook page, the charts I made before disappear.

I want to share the charts I created using Pygwalker with others, but they cannot see the charts through my shared ipynb file.

I want to know how to persist the charts I made through pygwalker.

Python - 3.11.3

I've already saved my notebook, but I found that my charts got cleared when I refresh it.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with, then we can both help you troubleshoot and better understand the issues you are having. Remember to add any specific information or errors involving your attempt. To learn more about how the [SO] community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### pygwalker(<0.2.0)

click "export_code", and copy code showed in modal.

[image]
[image]

### pygwalker(>=0.2.0)

version 0.2.0 has many important updates.

1. import pygwalker and your datas.

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   import pygwalker as pyg


   df = pd.read_csv("xxx")
   walker = pyg.walk(df, spec="config.json", use_preview=True)
   ```
2. explore datas and make charts, click "save" button to save your charts, chart config would save in the json file(spec).

[image]

3. use `display_chart` function to display your saved charts in any cells.

   ```py
   walker.display_chart("Your Chart Name")
   ```

more details about pygwalker(0.2.0): [here](https://docs.kanaries.net/en/pygwalker/changelog/pygwalker-0-2)